# Better way to restore svelte function?

Tags: svelte, contenteditable

```
<script>
  import { tick } from 'svelte';

  let cnt = 0;
  let tempValueforReset = true;

  const add = () => {
    cnt++;
  };
  
  const reset = async () => {
    tempValueforReset = false;
    await tick();
    tempValueforReset = true;
  };

</script>

{#if tempValueforReset}
  <div contenteditable="true">cnt is '{cnt}' !!</div>
{/if}

<div>
  <button on:click={add}>add</button>
  <button on:click={reset}>reset</button>
</div>
```

I am using the `contenteditable` attribute. This allows you to directly edit the content of the webpage. So sometimes it breaks the `svelte` syntax so it doesn't work anymore.

This is fine. This is the intended situation.

However, in order to recover this again, I am hiding the whole thing and displaying it again. It restores very well. But this doesn't seem like the normal way.

Is there a better regular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`{#key}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key), just set the trigger value to a different one, e.g. `Date.now()`.

```html
{#key resetValue}
  <div contenteditable="true">cnt is '{cnt}' !!</div>
{/key}

<button on:click={() => resetValue = Date.now()}>reset</button>
```